# bigquery create table from json definition gives STORAGE_FORMAT_UNSPECIFIED error

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I want to create a table by cloning the schema of an existing table, editing it by adding some columns, renaming others.

What I did is:

Find the schema of the table to clone:

```
bq show --format=json $dataset.$from_table | jq -c .schema
```

Edit it with some scripting, save as a file, e.g. schema.json (here simplified):

schema.json

```
{"fields":[{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"project_name","type":"STRING"},
{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"sample_name","type":"STRING"}]}
```

Then attempting to create the new table with the command below:

```
bq mk --table --external_table_definition=schema.json test- 
project1:dataset1.table_v1_2_2
```

But I am getting this error:

> BigQuery error in mk operation: Unsupported storage format for
>   external data: STORAGE_FORMAT_UNSPECIFIED

I just want this to be another table of the same type I have in the
system, which I believe is Location "Google Cloud BigQuery".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the `external_table_definition` flag, which is only relevant if you are creating an external table over files on GCS or Drive for example. A much easier way to go about creating the new table is to use a CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ... statement. As an example, suppose that I have a table `T1` with columns and types

```
foo: INT64
bar: STRING
baz: BOOL
```

I want to create a new table that renames `bar` and changes its type, and with the addition of a column named `id`. I can run a query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.T2 AS
SELECT
  foo,
  CAST(bar AS TIMESTAMP) AS fizz,
  baz,
  GENERATE_UUID() AS id
FROM dataset.T1
```

If you just want to clone and update the schema without incurring any cost or copying the data, you can use `LIMIT 0`, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.T2 AS
SELECT
  foo,
  CAST(bar AS TIMESTAMP) AS fizz,
  baz,
  GENERATE_UUID() AS id
FROM dataset.T1
LIMIT 0
```

Now you'll have a new, empty table with the desired schema.